# Issues in playing youtube videos in iOS 7 Beta Version

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios7, xcode5

I have an app on AppStore in which Youtube Video is working fine for earlier iOS versions (till iOS 6.1), But it is not working on iOS 7 Simulator.

**Issues:**

> 1) Youtube Video is playing with audio but with no display.
>
> 2) In an App, When Youtube video is playing and user clicks on done button. All layout get affected with black background.

So, Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Siddharth

Answer (score 2):

I have big issues with ios7 playing embedded youtube links as well.

I have video plugin that's not working properly anymore. Issues:
1 sometimes the video appeaers, sometimes not
2 when the video does not appear, i can still hear the audio if I click in the frame area
3 when the video appears I first clcik play; then a new play button appears in the control bar at the bottom of the player; and I have to click that button twice to make video play!

It's the same with embedded video links on other websites I have visited - ad if I make a simple embed video on my own site, same problem again.

My plugin and embedded yotube links worked perfectly witb Ios6. Guess this is just another example of how any new update swipes away old bugs while creating new ones. Bummer.

Cheers, hans

Comment: I'm playing youtubes with UIWebView; worked great under ios6 and now having all kinds of problems.  Odd error messages, slow loading and using too much memory.  I'm getting nowhere on it so far.